# Wicket 6: Link is not clickable in DataTable using LinkPropertyColumn

Tags: java, datatable, wicket

I want to generate a page which only consists of one datatable. In this datatable one column should consist of a link which does something when the user clicks on it.
It seems to be a straight forward task using the various implementations of the LinkPropertyColumn. I decided to use the implmentation provided [here](https://github.com/walokra/fotorest/blob/master/fotorest-wicket/src/main/java/com/ruleoftech/lab/components/LinkPropertyColumn.java) after testing a lot of slightly different implementations. All implementations provided the same result. The table was generated perfectly fine with the correct text but the generated links in the column were not clickable. When I click on them nothing happens. On mouse over they are also not underlined although they are represented in blue as a usual link. When I added some text I discovered, that the onClick method of the AjaxLink is never invoked. I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a hint.

Here is my Page class:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation("CHART_CONFIG_READ")
public class PrChartListPage extends PrBasePage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrChartListPage.class);

@SpringBean
private IPrChartDSP chartDSPRealizer;


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private SingleSortState sortState = new SingleSortState();

private PrDataTable<PrChartVO, String> mChartDataTable;

private PrProjectVO project;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public PrChartListPage(PageParameters params) {
    super(params);

    project=getActiveProject();


    // Deal with the ChartDataTable form
    Form<PrChartVO> lChartDataTableForm = new Form<PrChartVO>("chartDataTableForm");
    //      MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.authorize(lChartDataTableForm, RENDER, "USER");
    add(lChartDataTableForm);

    add(new Label("subTitle", new ResourceModel("chart.title", "Chart Configurator")));


    // Create and add the Chart list table to the page.
    addChartDataTable();

}

private void addChartDataTable() {
    List<IColumn<PrChartVO, String>> lColumns = new ArrayList<IColumn<PrChartVO, String>>();

    PrLinkPropertyColumn<PrChartVO> lChartNameColumn = new PrLinkPropertyColumn<PrChartVO>(
            new ResourceModel("chart.headerName"), "chart_name", "chart_name"){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(Item<ICellPopulator<PrChartVO>> cellItem, String componentId,
                        IModel<PrChartVO> model, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Object o = model.getObject();
                    if(o instanceof PrChartVO){
                        PrChartVO chart = (PrChartVO)o;
                        System.err.println("Chart: "+ chart.getChart_name()+" "+chart.getId());
                    }
                    else
                        System.err.println("Object is no chart!!! -> " + o.getClass().getName());

                }
    };
    lColumns.add(lChartNameColumn);


    PropertyColumn<PrChartVO, String> lChartTitleColumn = new PropertyColumn<PrChartVO, String>(new ResourceModel(
            "chart.headerTitle"), "title_text", "title_text");
    lColumns.add(lChartTitleColumn);

    PropertyColumn<PrChartVO, String> lChartTypeColumn = new PropertyColumn<PrChartVO, String>(new ResourceModel(
            "chart.headerChartType"), "chartTypeVO.type", "chartTypeVO.type");
    lColumns.add(lChartTypeColumn);

    PropertyColumn<PrChartVO, String> lXaxisTypeColumn = new PropertyColumn<PrChartVO, String>(
            new ResourceModel("chart.xaxisType"), "xAxisVO.name", "xAxisVO.name");
    lColumns.add(lXaxisTypeColumn);

    mChartDataTable = new PrDataTable<PrChartVO, String>("chartDataTable", lColumns, new ChartDataProvider(), PrConstants.pageSize, "100%");

    mChartDataTable.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    //      MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.authorize(mChartDataTable, RENDER, "USER");
    add(mChartDataTable);

}

@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {

    super.onBeforeRender();
}

private final class ChartDataProvider implements ISortableDataProvider<PrChartVO, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends PrChartVO> iterator(long first, long count) {

        if(project==null)
            System.err.println("Chart Iterator: Project is null");
        List<PrChartVO> lChartList = chartDSPRealizer.loadAllChartVOs(project);
        for (PrChartVO lChartVO : lChartList) {             
            if (lChartVO.getxAxisVO() != null && lChartVO.getxAxisVO().getName() != null) {
                String lXaxisName = new ResourceModel(lChartVO.getxAxisVO().getName()).getObject();                 
                lChartVO.getxAxisVO().setName(lXaxisName);
            }
        }
        return lChartList.subList((int)first, (int)(first + count)).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {

        int lRet = 0;
        if(project!=null)
            lRet = chartDSPRealizer.getChartCount(project);
        return lRet;
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<PrChartVO> model(PrChartVO object) {
        return new Model<PrChartVO>(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        // Ignore           
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public ISortState getSortState() {
        return sortState;
    }
}

}
```

This is the LinkPropertyColumn class

```
public abstract class PrLinkPropertyColumn<T> extends FilteredPropertyColumn<T, String> {

public PrLinkPropertyColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, IModel<T> labelModel) {
    super(displayModel, null);
}

public PrLinkPropertyColumn(final IModel<String> displayModel, final String sortProperty,
        final String propertyExpression) {
    super(displayModel, propertyExpression, sortProperty);
}

public PrLinkPropertyColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, String propertyExpressions) {
    super(displayModel, propertyExpressions);
}

@Override
public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<T> rowModel) {
    cellItem.add(new LinkPanel(cellItem, componentId, rowModel));
}

/**
 * Override this method to react to link clicks. Your own/internal row id
 * will most likely be inside the model.
 */
public abstract void onClick(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<T> model,
        AjaxRequestTarget target);

public class LinkPanel extends Panel {

    public LinkPanel(final Item<ICellPopulator<T>> cellItem, final String componentId, final IModel<T> model) {
        super(componentId);

        AjaxLink<T> link = new AjaxLink<T>("link") {

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println("This method is never invoked");
                PrLinkPropertyColumn.this.onClick(cellItem, componentId, model, target);
            }
        };
        link.add(new Label("label", getDataModel(model)));
        add(link);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.filter.
 * IFilteredColumn#getFilter(java.lang.String,
 * org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup
 * .html.repeater.data.table.filter.FilterForm)
 */
@Override
public Component getFilter(String componentId, FilterForm<?> form) {
    return new TextFilter<T>(componentId, getFilterModel(form), form);
}

protected IModel<T> getFilterModel(final FilterForm<?> form) {
    return new PropertyModel<T>(form.getDefaultModel(), getPropertyExpression());
}
}
```

I just want to mention that I am relatively new to wicket (we are using 6.19) and that I have to continue an exisiting project (and I do not have anybody to ask anymore). Thus, there might be somewhere some css or something else which I do not know of. If this might be the reason I would appreciate if you could give me a hint for what kind of setting I have to search.

Comment: First check with your browser's network monitor whether a request is sent when you click on the link.

Comment: Then put a breakpoint on ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#respond() and debug what Wicket is doing with this request.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. Unfortunately, I cannot provide solution because I just started from scratch and ended up with the same code only that it worked now. Magic :-)) Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar issue, it turned out that a parent component was disabling the links. They looked like links (blue text) but did not respond at all to scroll-over, clicking, etc.